# How to automatically provide a blank space after a question based on the solution size?

Tags: exsheets

I want to generate a problem booklet that provides a more accurate space after each question. As I always make the solution as general as possible, I think I can use the size of my solution for the size of the associated blank space. I don't want to use `\examspace` with hard-coded dimension as follows. How to implement my idea?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets
{
    question/name=Question,
    solution/name=Answer,
    solution/print=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Solve $2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x) = 1 - 2(2-3x)$.
\examspace{10\baselineskip}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{gather*}
2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x) = 1 - 2(2-3x) \\
\intertext{multiply both sides by 3}
3\times\left(2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x)\right) = 3\times\left(1 - 2(2-3x)\right) \\
6(x-1) - 2(3-2x) = 3 - 6(2-3x) \\
6x - 6 -6 +4x = 3 -12 +18x \\
10x -12 = -9 + 18x\\
10x -18x = -9 +12\\
-8x = 3\\
x = \frac{3}{-8}\\
x = -\frac{3}{8}
\end{gather*}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could put the solution in a box and use the height of the box as vertical space in the `{question}` and use the box in the `{solution}`.

Comment: @cgnieder: hopefully it becomes a new feature in the next release of `exsheets`.

Comment: I'm not so sure... But you never know. Maybe I'm bored some day and need something to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cgnieder has provided a good idea in comment, here is a code that implemented it:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets
{
    question/name=Question,
    solution/name=Answer,
    solution/print=true,
}

\begin{document}

\newbox\solboxone
\setbox\solboxone\vbox{
\begin{gather*}
2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x) = 1 - 2(2-3x) \\
\intertext{multiply both sides by 3}
3\times\left(2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x)\right) = 3\times\left(1 - 2(2-3x)\right) \\
6(x-1) - 2(3-2x) = 3 - 6(2-3x) \\
6x - 6 -6 +4x = 3 -12 +18x \\
10x -12 = -9 + 18x\\
10x -18x = -9 +12\\
-8x = 3\\
x = \frac{3}{-8}\\
x = -\frac{3}{8}
\end{gather*}
}

\begin{question}
Solve $2(x-1) - \frac{2}{3}(3-2x) = 1 - 2(2-3x)$a.
\vspace{\ht\solboxone}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\usebox\solboxone
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 : But the user interface is not so friendly. :-)

Comment: You will also want to consider adding a multiplication factor (>1) for the box height when the answers are handwritten and will take more space than printed ones.

Comment: I would like to use "vtop" instead of "vbox", but it seems that the variable "\ht\solboxone" is taken as zero when I replace "vbox" with "vtop" in the code above.

Any workaround?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: try `\dp\solboxone` instead of `\ht\solboxone`.

Comment: @Francis Ah, now I understand. Boxes have height and depth.

Comment: Apparently, I can't use this same variable "solboxone" for multiple solutions, writing \setbox\solboxone again and again. I guess that's because solboxone will always refer to the same object instance. It's boring to create a new box name for each question.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: I am pretty sure you can, just make sure `\setbox` after each instance of `\usebox`

Comment: @Francis Are you sure that works even if I choose to print all solutions only at the end of the chapter?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: oh, I guess that won't work. Old `solboxone` will be replaced by newly defined one.